# Combine string arrays lists and pass to a new array list only if a string exists in all original lists

Tags: string, loops, android-studio, arraylist

I have four ArrayLists and would like to combine them. New ArrayList should only contain strings that exist in all other array lists but only once. So far, I have the following code:

```
//Combine array lists and only keep duplicates
private ArrayList<String> getResultList(){
    final ArrayList<String> filtered_list = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(filtered_list);

    filtered_list.addAll(getResultList1());
    filtered_list.addAll(getResultList2());
    filtered_list.addAll(getResultList3());
    filtered_list.addAll(getResultList4());

    ArrayList<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : filtered_list) {
        if (!set.add(s)) {
            duplicates.add(s);
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

The result I currently get, if for example I only have 1 identical string in all four arrays, is a list of three identical strings in a list. Would I need to create a loop with HashSet inside it? I haven't seen any examples of this yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following code:

```
    //Combine array lists and only keep duplicates
    private ArrayList<String> getResultList(){
    final ArrayList<String> filtered_list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> filtered_list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> filtered_list = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(filtered_list1);
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(filtered_list2);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(filtered_list);

    filtered_list1.addAll(getResultList1());
    filtered_list1.addAll(getResultList2());

    filtered_list2.addAll(getResultList3());
    filtered_list2.addAll(getResultList4());

    ArrayList<String> duplicates1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : filtered_list1) {
        if (!set1.add(s)) {
            duplicates1.add(s);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> duplicates2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : filtered_list2) {
        if (!set2.add(s)) {
            duplicates2.add(s);
        }
    }

    filtered_list.addAll(duplicates1);
    filtered_list.addAll(duplicates2);

    ArrayList<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : filtered_list) {
        if (!set.add(s)) {
            duplicates.add(s);
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

There is probably an easier way of doing this but I haven't found it.